# Excel formula to return active days this year from license date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this:

| License Date | Active days 2023 |
| --- | --- |
| 13.09.2019 |  |
| 28.08.2023 |  |

And I need a formula that will return me the active days based on license date, for ex:

| License Date | Active days 2023 |
| --- | --- |
| 13.09.2019 | 255 |
| 10.09.2023 | 2 |

I have tried different things with DATE formula but haven't really got anything.
Also tried something with IF but likewise didn't return what I wanted :)

Comment: Usually subtraction works for dates like now() - 'specific date", or now() - A12 where A12 is a cell containing a formatted date.

Comment: Can you explain what 'Active Days' means? I can't imagine how you get 255 and 2 as shown in your example.

Comment: 12.09.2023 is the 255th day in 2023 @CLR so in 2023 there have been 255 active days for the license (I suppose)

Comment: What is license expiration date? Without expiration date, how you will count active days?

Comment: @CLR active days means for ex if the date was 01.01.2023 that means that 255 days passed in 2023, if that date is 08.09.2023 that means that 4 days have passed in 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=IF(YEAR(A2)<YEAR(TODAY());TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY());1;0);TODAY()-A2)
```

[image]

Today() - Date(Year(Today());1;0) is basically "today - the last day of last year".
Note that my date-format is a little different but you get the gist :)

Comment: Won't the licence expiration date have to be AFTER today to be valid? ie in the future...

Comment: OP said nothing about an expiration date, at least not from what I've seen from his question/example. Logically, yes, you'd want to calculate how many days are *left* on the license but there's no expiration date (yet).

Comment: hopefully the OP will get back  to us... Or the license date is associated with a duration like 2 years etc...

Comment: Yeah @Notus_Panda the formula worked like a charm